# Unable to set breakpoints in gdbserver via IDA

Tags: c, linux, gcc, reverse-engineering, ida

I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04 machine with binary exploitation exercises (learning how to use buffer overflows, write shellcodes, etc).
So far, I've been able to run these programs, written exclusively in C and compiled with gcc, via gdbserver and connect to it with IDA Pro 6.8 remotely.

However, right now there's a program that I'm trying to run and **it doesn't hit breakpoints set in IDA**. There's clearly communication between the two, and I can execute the program via IDA, but it doesn't stop at any breakpoints I set, including ones in the program's execution flow that would have definitely been hit. I set breakpoints on *addresses*, so unavailable debugging information can't be the reason.
Also, it works perfectly fine when I debug it with gdb.
I thought it was because I turned on ASLR, but when I turned it back off it still didn't work. What could be the reason?

The program was compiled like this (one file only):

gcc -pie -fPIE -fno-stack-protector -o prog prog.c

Answer (score 2):

In order for break points to work on lines or (not-exported) functions, the program needs to have debugging symbols. Your `gcc` command line does not include those. In that situation, if you were to create a break point on a *memory address*, the break point would work; but it does not work for lines and not-exported functions, since the necessary information for the debugger (or the `gdbserver` stub) is just not available.

To fix, add the `-g` parameter to your `gcc` command line.

Comment: Or -ggdb which is supposed to generate debugging info specifically for gdb.

Comment: I'm setting a break point on a memory address, it's worked before on programs not compiled with -g flag. See the edit plz.